# AndroidStudio shall not suggest variable names

Tags: android-studio, settings

Newest AndroidStudio believes to know the best variable names when I declare something. Typing `FileOutputStream fileout = ...` results in `FileOutputStream fileOutputStream` which ís absolutely not what I want and therefore annoys me. I found no option to switch this particular feature off.

I like autocompletion for types as there is no other choice but one of the list, I like autocompletion when is makes sense. But it does make no sense when I am free to choose any name.

I could press ESC every time but that's no reasonable option. Who can help me out?

For all who like to downvote everything: at least give a reason!

Comment: that might not be done

Comment: OMG ... this is a reason to back to the last version without this ... "feature" :-( sad sad!  Thanks for making clear why I don't find any solutions.

Comment: there are very less persons who dont require this option.